# Modular Application C++Builder

Tags: module, c++builder

I am trying to create a modular application using C++ Builder XE2.

Can anyone point me at an example. I need to be able to pass objects in and out of the modules.

For example the host application will have a database connection and the modules will need to be able to use this connection to run there queries, also any project they open I would like to pass this back to the host if they require a different module to do some processing on the project rather that reopening it.

I have looked at hydra but that is for Delphi.

Comment: besides database modules the Modules will also have visual forms that will need to be displayed.

Comment: After much more reading i finally worked it out, but i still don't get how i can access the methods in the form and how to pass objects from the host to the module and vice versa? i did try including the unit header file in teh host and teh host in the module but go errors.